# Treat \listofalgorithms the same as \listoftables and \listoffigures (i.e., having no number and not appearing in toc, but having bookmark)

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

In the working example below, how can I

1. remove the chapter number from "List of Algorithms",
2. remove "List of Algorithms" from the table of contents, and
3. keep the bookmark to "List of Algorithms"?

In other words, how can I make "List of Algorithms" be treated the same as "List of Figures" and "List of Tables"?

```
\documentclass[phd, final]{pittetd}
\usewithpatch{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\patch{amsmatch}
\patch{amsthm}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\title[A pittetd-thesis sample]{Sample file for a thesis with the `pittetd' class}
\author{I. M. Student}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This document is a sample file for the creation of ETD's at Pitt through \LaTeX.
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\listofalgorithms

\chapter{Introduction} 
In principio erat Verbum

\chapter{Second chapter}
This is the 2nd chapter.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    %\includegraphics{}
    \caption{Caption: fig.}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption: tab.}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\begin{algorithm} \small
\small
\caption{Caption: alg.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure {MyProcedure}{$a$}\\
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

Important info.

\chapter{Conclusions}
Concl.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer. Add code as shown here above `\listofalgorithms`:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listof[2]{%
\@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\def\@tempa{\section*}}%
{\def\@tempa{\section*}}%
\@tempa{#2\@mkboth{\uppercase{#2}}{\uppercase{#2}}}%
\@namedef{l@#1}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
\@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}}}
\makeatother

\null\vskip 1in
\makeatletter
        \hypertarget{prelim.7}{}%
        \protected@write\@outlinefile{}{%
            \protect\BOOKMARK
            [0][]{prelim.7}{LIST OF ALGORITHMS}{}%
            \protect\begingroup\protect\makeatletter
            \protect\prepare@bookmarks7
            \protect\@input{\jobname.loa}
            \protect\endgroup}
\makeatother
\listofalgorithms
```

The entire working example is shown below:

```latex
\documentclass[phd, final]{pittetd}
\usewithpatch{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\patch{amsmatch}
\patch{amsthm}

\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{titletoc}

\title[A pittetd-thesis sample]{Sample file for a thesis with the `pittetd' class}
\author{I. M. Student}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This document is a sample file for the creation of ETD's at Pitt through \LaTeX.
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\listof[2]{%
\@ifundefined{ext@#1}{\float@error{#1}}{%
\@ifundefined{chapter}{\def\@tempa{\section*}}%
{\def\@tempa{\section*}}%
\@tempa{#2\@mkboth{\uppercase{#2}}{\uppercase{#2}}}%
\@namedef{l@#1}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
\@starttoc{\@nameuse{ext@#1}}}}
\makeatother

\null\vskip 1in
\makeatletter
        \hypertarget{prelim.7}{}%
        \protected@write\@outlinefile{}{%
            \protect\BOOKMARK
            [0][]{prelim.7}{LIST OF ALGORITHMS}{}%
            \protect\begingroup\protect\makeatletter
            \protect\prepare@bookmarks7
            \protect\@input{\jobname.loa}
            \protect\endgroup}
\makeatother
\listofalgorithms


\chapter{Introduction} 
In principio erat Verbum

\chapter{Second chapter}
This is the 2nd chapter.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    %\includegraphics{}
    \caption{Caption: fig.}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
         &  \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption: tab.}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\begin{algorithm} \small
\small
\caption{Caption: alg.}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure {MyProcedure}{$a$}\\
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

Important info.

\chapter{Conclusions}
Concl.

\end{document}
```